# InvalidValueError: in property origin: not a string; and not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object; and not an Object

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am using angular google maps to set the current position and agm-direction to set the direction. Below is the code and I am getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: Are you sure that any values are assigned to the class properties (`lat` and `lng`) when `getDirection` method is called?

Comment: please log this.lat and this.lng inside getCurrentPosition callback function and make sure you are getting the values

Comment: Try this in Mozilla.. got some restrictions in Chrome for HTTPS I guess.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-geolocation-blitz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @JEMI I am getting the values . One thing i noticed is that directions works fine with the below lat and lng for origin. this.origin = { lat: 24.799534, lng: 120.975555 }; this.destination = { lat: 24.799524, lng: 120.975017 }; But doesnt work ( when i click directions button , nothing happens )with the below values. this.origin = { lat: 13.0191018, lng: 77.6642952 }; this.destination = { lat: 24.799524, lng: 120.975017 }; Why is it so?

Answer (score 2):

This will be probably because your `lat`, `lng` of your component aren't populated when you call `getDirections()`. `getUserLocation()` won't result in position coordinates synchronously. You can check the code under `getUserLocation()` by pasting in your browser console. You will see that it takes time to give you positions. If you are calling `getDirections()` in between the time taken to give the result.. you would be getting the above said errors.

I made the `getDirections()` like this:

```
async getDirection() {
    if (typeof this.lat == "undefined" || typeof this.lng == "undefined" || typeof this.zoom == "undefined") {
      await this.getUserLocation();
    }
    // code below will not be executed until getUserLocation() is complete
    this.origin = { lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng };
    this.destination = { lat: 24.799524, lng: 120.975017 };
}
```

Your `getUserLocation()` will be called at max twice..

Answer (score 0):

Note: make sure you call get get direction after setting data to lat ,lon  variables to avoid race condition. and parse your values as Float like in  the code snippet below

```
 getDirection() {
    this.origin = { lat: parseFloat(this.startLat), lng: parseFloat(this.startLon) };
    this.destination = { lat:parseFloat(this.endLat), lng: parseFloat(this.endLon) };


    console.log(this.origin, this.destination);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case in JS Map API  samples for Directions Service I copied this code :

```
origin: {
    query: document.getElementById("start").value,
  }
```

where you should  use only:

```
origin: value  //LatLng, String of address or google.maps.Place
```

Then replaced that `{query:..}` with LatLng object and the error gone.
I found it reasonable to put here this answer because people like me copy past samples' code to gain time and trust it and dont see or understand what is this.